# How to create a dynamic query which looks at x date gives me all records for 2 weeks before and after x date?

Tags: dynamic, hana

I am using HANA and I have two tables. Both tables have

1. Customer_Number
2. Transaction_Number
3. Transaction_Date
4. Transaction_Week
5. Spend
6. Means_of_Payment

The only difference in the TYPE of information between the tables is the Means_of_Payment. Table 1 has transactions paid with the debit card or credit card and table 2 has transactions paid with a gift card or a voucher. The customers in table 1 are the same as customers in table 2

**Focus**: Customers use gift card/vouchers mostly in Apr

**My aim**: What is a customer’s spend 2 weeks before their transaction in April and 2 weeks after their transaction in April. Idea is to see if and how their spend changed after using a gift card/voucher

**Problem**: Each customer’s Apr transaction date will be different so I need to create a dynamic query that will look up a customer’s transaction date in the month of April (table 2) and give me their spend 2 weeks before and after that date (table 1) and I’m really unsure about how to do this.

**Expected Result**: Customer 1 Apr transaction date = 1/04/2018 so their relevant date range is 2 weeks before 1/04/2018 and 2 weeks after.
Customer 2 Apr transaction date = 5/04/2018 so their relevant date range in 2 weeks before 5/04/2018 and 2 weeks after.

I want to return the transaction_number, spend and Means_of_payment in each customer's relevant date range

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your help

I only have code that is joining the two tables

```
SELECT *
FROM "Table2" AS A
LEFT JOIN "Table1" AS B
ON A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 tables with the same structure? It is bad design on any DB, but especially on HANA

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT cards.*
FROM "Table2" AS coupons

    JOIN "Table1" AS cards
ON coupons.CUSTOMER = coupons.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
    and cards.Transaction_Date between ADD_DAYS(coupons.Transaction_Date, -14) and 
              ADD_DAYS(coupons.Transaction_Date, 14)
```